# 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default Firebase Database instance. Must call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have development and production firebase projects, and I am managing using below method,

In my AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions,

```
// Configure with manual options.
    let secondaryOptions = FirebaseOptions(googleAppID: "1:82121212:ios:212121212121212", gcmSenderID: "872909116998")
    secondaryOptions.bundleID = "com.testApp.test"
    secondaryOptions.apiKey = "AIzasskjkkjhkdhksadhsadaskdhks"
    secondaryOptions.clientID = "82121212-asdsdasdasdasdasdadsdsd.apps.googleusercontent.com"
    secondaryOptions.databaseURL = "https://test-myApp.firebaseio.com"
    secondaryOptions.storageBucket = "test-myApp.appspot.com"

    // Configure an alternative FIRApp.
    FirebaseApp.configure(name: "secondary", options: secondaryOptions)
    guard let secondary = FirebaseApp.app(name: "secondary")
        else { assert(false, "Could not retrieve secondary app") }
    let secondaryDb = Database.database(app: secondary)
```

and in my another view controller while fetching messages from the firebase database my application is crashing with 
"*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FIRAppNotConfigured', reason: 'Failed to get default Firebase Database instance. Must call `[FIRApp configure]` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) before using Firebase Database.'"

my ChatViewController

```
class ChatViewController : UIViewController {

var ref : DatabaseReference!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getChatMessages()
}

@objc func getChatMessages() {

    firebase = Database.database().reference(fromURL: url)
    Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: firBaseAuthToken, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil{
        }
        else
        {
            let userAuthData = user?.additionalUserInfo
            self.uid = (user?.user.uid)!.replacingOccurrences(of: ".", with: "")
            self.successFireBaseAuth(urlString: klUrl)
        }
    })

}

func successFireBaseAuth(urlString : String)
{
    ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: urlString)


    ref.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
 })
}
```

Comment: look like you are giving wrong name of application.

Comment: no, I confirmed and the name is the same in the firebase dashboard and mentioned in Applegate.

Comment: PROJECT_ID , REVERSED_CLIENT_ID are missing too, just download plist from firebase and tally each argument.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you are accessing the wrong instance of app.

```
    guard let secondary = FirebaseApp.app(name: "secondary")
        else { assert(false, "Could not retrieve secondary app") }
    let secondaryDb = Database.database(app: secondary)
```

Your own code in AppDelegate, I'm assuming thats how you should get the right database instance.

but you are using

```
Database.database()
```

When trying to get messages.

If you want to use the shared instance use

```
FirebaseApp.configure(options: secondaryOptions)
```

when configuring

Comment: But how should find that I am getting the right instance of the database?

Comment: Well if you give it a name while configuring firebase app, it's not accessible from shared instance ( I.E: database() )
so you should call the right firebase.app like mentioned in the snippet in my comment, if you want to configure the shared instance you should drop the name and initialize using the configure(options: yourOptions)